# How to add Multi-Project Throttle Category using script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, throttling, jenkins-groovy

I am using Jenkins with Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin and trying to add Throttle Category in jenkins configuration(Jenkins=>manage Jenkins=> Configure System=>Throttle Concurrent Builds). Is it possible to configure it using groovy? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 String expectedLabel = "testLabel";
 Integer expectedMax = new Integer(1);

 ThrottleJobProperty.ThrottleCategory category =
 new ThrottleJobProperty.ThrottleCategory('testCategoryName3', 0, 0, null);
 List<ThrottleJobProperty.NodeLabeledPair> nodeLabeledPairs = category.getNodeLabeledPairs();
 nodeLabeledPairs.add(new ThrottleJobProperty.NodeLabeledPair(expectedLabel, expectedMax));

  ThrottleJobProperty.DescriptorImpl descriptor = Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptorByType(ThrottleJobProperty.DescriptorImpl.class)

  categories = descriptor.getCategories()
  categories.add(category)
  descriptor.save()
```